# Clicking an image on form1 shows same image on form2

Tags: vb.net

I have tried for ages to figure this out. Please help if you can.

---

I have 2 forms.

1. I want the user to click on 1 of 3 images on form1
2. click the 'next' button to be taken to form2
3. then have form2 display the relevant image.

At the moment I have managed to make each image glow when the mouse hovers over, here's part of my code for that in case it's relevant. Thanks!

```
Private Sub pbBook_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object,
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles pbBook.MouseEnter

    pbBook.Image() = Project2Game.My.Resources.Resources.bookglow
    pbBookDescription.Show()

End Sub


Private Sub pbBook_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object,
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles pbBook.MouseLeave

    pbBook.Image() = Project2Game.My.Resources.Resources.book
    pbBookDescription.Hide()

End Sub
```

Comment: Add a constructor to `Form2` that has an `Image` parameter and use that to create the `Form2` instance in `Form1`.  Then you simply pass in the `Image` you want to use.  Obviously you need to write code in `Form2` to use that `Image`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm really new to all this and unfortunately I don't understand what you said there. I'll keep trying.

Comment: You know how to write methods, right?  A constructor is a method named `New`.  It's the method that gets executed when you create a new object of that type.  If you declare a parameter with that method then you will have to pass a value to that parameter when you call the method.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of thing I was describing in my comment:

In `Form2`:

```
Public Sub New(image As Image)
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    Me.PictureBox1.Image = image
End Sub
```

In `Form1`:

```
Dim f2 As New Form2(myImage)

f2.Show()
```